# Parole GPS monitor on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, muktzeh, eruv-chatzerot

Someone who was just released from jail. He is still serving parole and must wear a GPS monitor around his ankle.

1) Is the GPS monitor able to be worn on Shabbos?  And if yes;
2) Is it allowed to be worn outside of an Eruv?

Comment: It's a good question, but seems like a Request for Pesak. I tried editing it, but not sure if I did a sufficient job.

Comment: [This](http://hamodia.com/2015/11/25/pollard-parole-restrictions-conflicts-with-shemiras-shabbos/) article seems to imply that there isn't an issue (it brought up charging problem, but not wearing a GPS device).

Comment: I would assume the same halacha would apply by wearing hearing aides.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The article does say that he would be unable to go to a minyan, but is unclear if that is because it would cause the battery to discharge or because he could not wear it outside. Perhaps, since it cannot be removed, it may be considered like "clothing".

Comment: Why would this be different than any other article of clothing regarding question 2?

Comment: @DonielF that is precisely the שאלה- is it considered like clothing or not?

Comment: But why would you think it’s not?

Comment: @DonielF I don't know whether it is or not but I would appreciate sources to back up your claim

Comment: I’m not claiming anything. I’m asking why you think this would be different.

Comment: @DonielF I'm sorry.  Maybe it would be different bec. the person is not using it to clothe himself, but maybe that doesn't make a difference. By submitting the question I gave the users a chance to discuss it :)

Comment: Perhaps jewelry would be a better comparison?

Comment: Well they're not using it for jewelry purposes either.